# Angular 2 form submit

Tags: angular

While is was working on an form in angular 2 I ran into a problem. when using the following form and my submit doesn't work:

```
<form #addForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="add()">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button [class.disabled]="!addForm.valid" type="submit"
              class="btn btn-primary col-xs-12">+</button>
    </span>
    <input required name="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="name" [(ngModel)]="newAlbum.name">
  </div>
</form>
```

But by adding  `(click)="add()"` to the button I can submit the form by pressing enter. can anyone explain this to me.

Comment: I don't understand what "But by adding  (click)="add()" I can submit the form by pressing enter." means. Also what does "doesn't work mean". Can you please try to explain again what the expected behavior is and what the current behavior is?

Comment: your form seems to use some bad practices, you should take another look at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html for correct form implementation

Comment: @nusje2000. Could you provide a plunker, I could not reproduce your issue :)

Comment: and besides, don't you want a click event on button, so that user can actually submit the form by clicking the button as well??

Comment: Yea I do want the user to be able to submit the form but if I follow the angular 2 forms tutorial they say that it should act like a normal HTML form in a way that if you add a submit button it will submit the form.

Comment: Yes, I understand. That's why I asked for a plunker, since there is no error in your above code. I tried it, and for me it worked fine with your code. Form could be submitted both with enterkey and by clicking button :) WITHOUT the `(click)="add()"`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If found a solution:

```
<button 
  [disabled]="!addForm.valid"
  (click)="add()">+</button>
```

By adding the `[disabled]` binding the button will disable itself when the form is not correct. It might not be the correct way of implementation but it does work. If anyone has a better solution please mention it but for now this problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

In onSubmit call you need to pass the form i:e `onSubmit(myForm)`

I think you are confused between model and template driven forms. Please go through them first.

Comment: this is wath te documentation of angular sais: <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #heroForm="ngForm">